# Python args: django debugging arg set up for django manage.py

Tags: python, django, arguments, ptvs

I want to enable debugging using visual studio debugging tool, `ptvsd`. Using that I have to attach the debugger to the application using

```
ptvsd.enable_attach(address=(settings.REMOTE_URL, settings.DEBUG_PORT), redirect_output=True)
ptvsd.wait_for_attach()
```

Using ptvsd means I can't use threading and reloading, so I append the args

```
sys.argv.append("--nothreading")
sys.argv.append("--noreload")
```

For convenience to enable debugging I created an args to execute those line of codes. I created named argument `debug`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #previous line omitted
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--debug", help="enable debugging through vscode")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.debug:
        sys.argv.append("--nothreading")
        sys.argv.append("--noreload")
        ptvsd.enable_attach(address=(settings.REMOTE_URL, settings.DEBUG_PORT), redirect_output=True)
        ptvsd.wait_for_attach()
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

What I want to achieve is, when I want to debug my app I use the command 
`python manage.py runserver 0:8000 --enable-debugging` and when I just want to run my app I use `python manage.py runserver 0:8000`

but it returns an error when I tried to run using 
`python manage.py runserver 0:8000` it says unrecognized arguments for `runserver` and `0:8000`

by that, do I have to include all possible django positional argument to the `parser` ? and how to do that with the `0:8000`? add all possible port?
Is using named argument not viable for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I can use `parser.parse_known_args()`, it should be fine when there are unrecognized arguments. and because I want the `--debug` as a flag, I add `action='store_true'` in the add_argument so it returns true whenever the argument exists.

With that, I can solve this by using that and then remove the `--debug` argument when passing it down to `execute_from_command_line`. Something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #previous line omitted
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--debug", action='store_true', help="enable debugging through vscode")
    args = vars(parser.parse_known_args()[0])
    if args.debug:
        sys.argv.append("--nothreading")
        sys.argv.append("--noreload")
        ptvsd.enable_attach(address=(settings.REMOTE_URL, settings.DEBUG_PORT), redirect_output=True)
        ptvsd.wait_for_attach()
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Now it works :)